# Angular HTTP get JSON not getting JSON

Tags: sql, angularjs, json, scope

I have JSON data from a database:

{"user":"Rob",,{"user":"John",,{"user":"Chris",, etc etc

I am using Angular to get the JSON and place it in an HTML table.

```
  <table>
   <tr>
    <th>Username:</th>
     </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
<td>{{ x.user}}</td>
```

Using the following script:

```
 <script>
   arudate.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     $http.get("sqlTest.php")
   .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
      });
 </script>
```

But I get nothing as in no JSON, even though it is showing as retrieved at sqlTest.php

Can anyone offer any assistance or troubleshooting please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `sqlTest.php` script sets the proper response `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. Otherwise angular wouldn't know to automatically process the response. If your server script doesn't return proper headers you might need to manually parse the response to a javascript object:

```
$http.get('sqlTest.php').success(function (response) {
    $scope.names = JSON.parse(response).records;
});
```

Also make sure that your JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "records": [
        { "user": "Bob" },
        { "user": "John" },
        { "user": "Chris" },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Another thing you should be looking at is the console of your web browser's developer toolbar for any potential errors.

Comment: Thanks but I don;t think that's it. The code works fine for all my other databases but not for this one.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also did you check the Network tab to see if the AJAX request succeeds and returns 200?

Answer (score 0):

You're only showing the top of the table html - can we assume you've got a complete table structure here?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
        <td>{{ x.user}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It also makes for much clearer code if you use the singular form of your arrays for the iterator name, for example 'name in names' instead of 'x in names', and in this case you're getting an array of people or users and displaying their names, so I would suggest this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Username:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm not *exactly* sure what your data looks like, but if you're getting a list of users it should be structured something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bob"
    },
    {
        "name": "John"
    },
    {
        "name": "Chris"
    }
]
```

Try saving out your json file as text and loading it from the file system first before you fetch from a live data source/database, and pass the json file through http://jsonlint.com first to make sure it's valid. That way you're only troubleshooting your code, not also a possibly faulty data format and a data service that may or may not always be responsive.